# Deploy Jira REST API to Googe Bigquery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, cloud, jira, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to move data from Jira to Google Bigquery for analytics reason. Is there a way to call REST API in AppEngin or Dataflow. I also want to schedule for these API to update data frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Both app engine and dataflow should be able to make direct [REST API calls to Jira here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/).

Both the services essentially spin up compute on top of which the user code runs and you can call remote api's via the code by conforming to the guidelines described in the [url](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/).

Once you have successfully tests dataflow job pipeline, you can invoke this job via App Engine cron to launch it periodically. To give an example, the implementation can be [similar to this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/analyzing-tweets-using-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-templates) but instead of calling twitter api user has to call Jira.